# Error:'Not supported on current platform' while using jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod() in cocos2d js v3

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-js

In my cocos2d js android app I am using `jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod()` to run some java code.

But in the log i get 'JS: not supported on current platform' ...

The documentation says it works on version 3 which is the one i am using...

I use it as

`var result = jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("org/cocos2dx/javascript/Test", "sum", "(II)I", 3, 7);
        cc.log(result); //10`

My Test.java

```
  package org.cocos2dx.javascript;

 public class Test {

public static void hello(String msg){
    System.out.println(msg);
}

public static int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

public static int sum(int a){
    return a + 2;
}

}
```

Am i making any mistake....
Any help regarding this would be greatful...

Thanks.